# Python logging - display the name of the script that triggers the custom logging module

Tags: python, logging

I would like to get the name of the script that triggers a custom logging module.
The formatter of the logging module called `module_x` is saved in `logger.py` and looks like:

```
import logging.config
import sys

class ConsoleFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, datefmt, output_format):
        super().__init__()
        self.datefmt = datefmt
        self.output_format = output_format

        """Logging Formatter to add colors and count warning / errors"""
        INFO = '\033[94m'
        DEBUG = '\033[37m'
        WARNING = '\033[33m'
        FAIL = '\033[91m'
        ENDC = '\033[0m'
        BOLD = '\033[1m'
        formatting = output_format

        self.FORMATS = {
            logging.DEBUG: DEBUG + formatting + BOLD + ENDC,
            logging.INFO: INFO + formatting + BOLD +ENDC,
            logging.WARNING: WARNING + formatting + BOLD + ENDC,
            logging.ERROR: FAIL + formatting + BOLD + ENDC,
            logging.CRITICAL: FAIL + formatting + BOLD + ENDC
        }

    def format(self, record):
        log_fmt = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_fmt, datefmt=self.datefmt)
        return formatter.format(record)


class Log(ConsoleFormatter):

    def __init__(self, datefmt=None, format=None, handlers=None):

        if datefmt == None:
            datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        if format == None:
            format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s] %(message)s"

        super().__init__(datefmt, format)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('test')

...
```

In `test.py` I am triggering the module using:

```
logs = Log()
logs.output(msg="This is the first test.", level="INFO")
```

With this piece of code, the display that I am getting is:

```
2022-01-11 16:15:28 [INFO] [logger.py] This is the first test.
```

I would like to get the name of the file that is triggering the `logger.py` which is `test.py`, not `logger.py`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show your `output` function of your `Log` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [name a logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) when calling `getLogger` and you can then use this as `%(name)s` in your logger format.

So in `test.py` you could call with the current file name:

```py
import os

logs = Log(name=os.path.basename(__file__))
logs.output(msg="This is the first test.", level="INFO")
```

and change your definition of the Log class in `logger.py` to something like this:

```py
class Log(ConsoleFormatter):

    def __init__(self, name="test", datefmt=None, format=None, handlers=None):  ##

        if datefmt == None:
            datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        if format == None:
            format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s"  ##

        super().__init__(datefmt, format)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)  ##
```

(Changed lines marked with `##`)